# Elabore un codigo para leer la temperatura de celsius a farenheit y a kelvin pero cuando pulso la opcion 3 me retorna las opciones y no la solucion

Tags: python-2.7

```
def fahrenheit_celsius():
    '''convierte temperatura en grados fahrenheit a grados celsius'''
    fahrenheit = int(input('Ingrese la temperatura en grados Fahrenheit: '))
    celsius = (fahrenheit -32 ) * 5.0/9.0
    return '{} grados Fahrenheit son {} grados Celsius'.format(fahrenheit, celsius)
def celsius_fahrenheit():
    '''convierte temperatura en grados celsius a fahrenheit'''
    celsius = int(input('Ingrese la temperatura en grados Celsius: '))
    fahrenheit = 9.0/5.0 * celsius +32
    return '{} grados Fahrenheit son {} grados Celsius'.format(fahrenheit, celsius)
def celsius_kelvin():
   '''convierte temperatura en grados celsius a kelvin'''
   celsius = int(input('Ingrese la temperatura en grados Celsius: '))
   kelvin = celsius +273.15
   return '{} grados Celsius son {} grados Kelvin'.format(celsius, kelvin)
while True:
    print('1.- Fahrenheit a Celsius')
    print('2.- Celsius a Fahrenheit')
    print('3.- Celsius a Kelvin')
    try:
        opcion = int(input('Seleccione una opcion: '))
        if opcion == 1:
            print(fahrenheit_celsius())
        elif opcion == 2:
            print(celsius_fahrenheit())
        elif opcion == 3:
            print(celsius_kelvin)  
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print('Ingrese solo numeros.(1/3)')
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, modifica tu pregunta usando el boton [edit] y utiliza la opcion de identar codigo para ver exactamente como tenes tu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes llamar a la función `celsius_kelvin`, como:

```
print(celsius_kelvin())
```

Comment: Entonces, es simplemente un error tipografico? Tene en cuenta que si es asi, se puede contestar en un comentario, y tambien la pregunta se cierra por ese motivo

Comment: Correcto. Gracias

Comment: Considere marcar como respuesta. Gracias https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/120826